# Proper way to fetch user profiles

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm working on a site that has many user pages which have different components like comments, posts and so on. I'm using mongodb which doesn't inherently support associations (even though I'm using Waterline I'd like to avoid relying on associations). I wish to know what's the "usual" or recommended way to fetch user details associated with each component.

Things I've tried:

1. Populating the User field of each item manually - This incurs a lot of extra code and isn't feasible because items can be nested and the user fields don't all have the same attribute name (making it impossible to populate items using a generic piece of code).
2. Using associations - This works well one level deep, but populating nested items is again a problem. To have the fields populated via associations, I'll have to make calls at every alternate level.
3. Sending all users as an id:profile map - This is what I'm currently doing. This requires extra work too (more than method 1), since I bundle all required uids into a single object (to avoid repetition) and call `Object.keys()` on it to obtain an array based on which I query for users. I then map the users array into an Object like before and send it to the rendering engine. This feels like the best way since I get a lot of flexibility on the view side, but the work required at the controller-end is a little too much.

Is there an easier/better/recommended way out?

I'm using Sails for this development.